# No image appearing on pane, how to fix this?

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote this java application on NetBeans IDE 8.2 to show an image stored on my local directory in the same directory of the classes files directory (as stated in the documentation), but when running there is no image appearing on the scene although there is no exception,, anyone has any idea how to fix this??

```
            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
            import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
            import javafx.geometry.Insets;
            import javafx.scene.image.Image;
            import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
            import javafx.geometry.Insets;
            import java.io.File;

            public class ShowImage extends Application{
                @Override
                public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                    Pane pane = new HBox();
                    pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

                    Image image = new Image("image.jpg");
                    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

                    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
                    imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
                    imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
                    pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

                    ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
                    imageView3.setRotate(90);
                    pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);

                    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
                    primaryStage.setTitle("Show Image");
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.show();

                }
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Application.launch(args);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to this repeated problem is to create a new sub packadge from NetBeans under your packadge, name it "resources" for example and and put the your image in the directory of the sub package and edit the path in the code as this

```
Image image = new Image("resources/image.jpg");
```

this will avoid the path issues, and route the file from package directly.